# Pulling images from private repository in kubernetes without using imagePullSecrets

Tags: docker, kubernetes, registry, private, jfrog-container-registry

I am new to kubernetes deployments so I wanted to know is it possible to pull images from private repo without using `imagePullSecrets` in the deployment yaml files or is it mandatory to create a docker registry secret and pass that secret in imagePullSecrets.
I also looked at adding imagePullSecrets to a service account but that is not the requirement I woul love to know that if I setup creds in variables can kubernetes use them to pull those images.
Also wanted to know how can it be achieved and reference to a document would work
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you're using Docker on your Kubernetes nodes (please note that Docker support has itself [recently been deprecated in Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/12/02/dont-panic-kubernetes-and-docker/)), you can authenticate the Docker engine on your nodes itself against your private registry.

Essentially, this boils down to running `docker login` on your machine and then copying the resulting credentials JSON file directly onto your nodes. This, of course, only works if you have direct control over your node configuration.

See [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#configuring-nodes-to-authenticate-to-a-private-registry) for more information:

> If you run Docker on your nodes, you can configure the Docker container runtime to authenticate to a private container registry.
>
> This approach is suitable if you can control node configuration.
>
> Docker stores keys for private registries in the `$HOME/.dockercfg` or `$HOME/.docker/config.json` file. If you put the same file in the search paths list below, kubelet uses it as the credential provider when pulling images.
>
> - `{--root-dir:-/var/lib/kubelet}/config.json`
> - `{cwd of kubelet}/config.json`
> - `${HOME}/.docker/config.json`
> - `/.docker/config.json`
> - `{--root-dir:-/var/lib/kubelet}/.dockercfg`
> - `{cwd of kubelet}/.dockercfg`
> - `${HOME}/.dockercfg`
> - `/.dockercfg`
>
> Note: You may have to set `HOME=/root` explicitly in the environment of the kubelet process.
>
> Here are the recommended steps to configuring your nodes to use a private registry. In this example, run these on your desktop/laptop:
>
> - Run `docker login [server]` for each set of credentials you want to use. This updates `$HOME/.docker/config.json` on your PC.
> - View `$HOME/.docker/config.json` in an editor to ensure it contains just the credentials you want to use.
> - Get a list of your nodes; for example:
>
>   - if you want the names: `nodes=$( kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{range.items[*].metadata}{.name} {end}' )`
>   - if you want to get the IP addresses: `nodes=$( kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{range .items[*].status.addresses[?(@.type=="ExternalIP")]}{.address} {end}' )`
> - Copy your local `.docker/config.json` to one of the search paths list above.
>   for example, to test this out: `for n in $nodes; do scp ~/.docker/config.json root@"$n":/var/lib/kubelet/config.json; done`
>
> **Note:** For production clusters, use a configuration management tool so that you can apply this setting to all the nodes where you need it.

Comment: If I recall it right credentials in config.json are not encrypted, is there a solution to prevent this?

Comment: @cnu You could have a look at the ["Docker credential helpers" project](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers) -- I haven't used it myself (and cannot attest to how well it works), but it claims to integrate Docker credential storage with native operating system capabilities (like the D-BUS secret service on Linux)

Answer (score 0):

If the Kubernetes cluster is private, you can deploy your own, private (and free) [JFrog Container Registry](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/JFrog+Container+Registry) using its [Helm Chart](https://chartcenter.io/jfrog/artifactory-jcr) in the same cluster.

Once it's running, you should allow anonymous access to the registry to avoid the need for a login in order to pull images.

If you prevent external access, you can still access the internal k8s service created and use it as your "private registry".

Read through the documentation and see the various options.

Another benefit is that JCR (JFrog Container Registry) is also a Helm repository and a generic file repository, so it can be used for more than just Docker images.

---